# Display tree structure in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jstree

I anyone help me out to display the tree structure in view. I have successfully created the parent child associations between single table called "Element". Also the entries are saving in proper manner.

I have build the code for that but it works at a level, because I have used the loop I want to optimize that, I hope seeing the code you could have the quick solutions.

```
class Element
  include Mongoid::Document
  validates :name, presence: true

  field :name, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :top, type: String

  has_many :media_files

  has_and_belongs_to_many :parents, :class_name => 'Element'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :childrens, :class_name => 'Element'

  def self.js_tree
    json_data = Array.new
    elements = Element.where(top: "true")
    get_inner_elements elements, json_data
   return json_data.uniq {|e| e[:id] }.to_json
  end

  def self.get_inner_elements elements, json_data
    elements.each do |element|
      single_element element, json_data
      element.childrens.each do |inner_element_one|
        single_element inner_element_one, json_data, element.id
        inner_element_one.childrens.each do |inner_element_two|
          single_element inner_element_two, json_data, inner_element_one.id
          inner_element_two.childrens.each do |inner_element_three|
            single_element inner_element_three, json_data, inner_element_two.id
            inner_element_three.childrens.each do |inner_element_four|
              single_element inner_element_four, json_data, inner_element_three.id
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
    return json_data
  end

  def self.single_element element, json_data, parent=nil
    json_data << { 
        :id     => "#{element.id}", 
        :parent => "#{parent.nil? ? '#' : parent}",
        :a_attr=> { class: "foldor-icon" },
        :text   => "#{element.name}"
      }
      element.media_files.each do |mf|
        json_data << { 
          :id     => "file_#{element.id}_#{mf.id}",
          :parent => "#{element.id}", 
          :text   => mf.file_filename,
          :icon     => mf.icon,
        }
      end
    return json_data  
  end

end
```

Front End :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  data = $.parseJSON('<%= raw Element.js_tree %>')
  $('#container').jstree({
   'core' : {
      'data' : data
    }
  });
</script>
```

The get_inner_elements need to be optimized Please anyone suggest how to do that there is something recursion need to be used I am unable to apply that.

Thannks

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try using a recursive algorithm.

```
def self.get_inner_elements(elements, json_data)
    elements.each do |element|
        if elements.children.count > 0
            single_element(element, json_data, element.parent?)
            get_inner_elements(element.children, json_data)
        else
            single_element(element, json_data, element.parent?)
        end
    end
    json_data
end
```

It may be not perfectly optimized, but it is a bit more readable than that big tree you have.

One caveat here is that not the same order of elements will be preserved, if this is not one of the requirements, you can use it easily, if not, you will have to re-order the `json_data` you have on the output